# Exibir posts e imagem de destaque usando API REST Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Quero exibir os dois últimos posts do Wordpress usando API Rest, depois de muitas pesquisas e teste conseguir fazer essa gambiarra aí, mas depois que coloquei esse foreach dentro do outro ficou meio lento, seria bom se tivesse como mostrar as imagens de cada posts sem precisar de um novo foreach.

**Será que tem como simplificar este código?**

```
<?php
    $posts = file_get_contents('http://localhost/noticias/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=true?per_page=2');
    $obj = json_decode($posts);
    foreach ($obj as $post) {
        echo '<div class="posts">';

        $id = ($post->id);
        $thumbnail = file_get_contents('http://localhost/noticias/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=' . $id . '');
        $images = json_decode($thumbnail);
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            echo '<img src="' . $image->media_details->sizes->medium_large->source_url . '"/>';
        }
        echo '<h2><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->title->rendered . '</a></h2>';
        echo '<p>' . $post->excerpt->rendered . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $post->date . '</p>';

        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
    $posts = file_get_contents('http://localhost/noticias/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=2');
    $obj = json_decode($posts);
    foreach ($obj as $post) {
        echo '<div class="posts">';
        $thumbnail = file_get_contents('http://localhost/noticias/wp-json/wp/v2/media/' . $post->featured_media);
        $image = json_decode($thumbnail);
        echo '<img src="' . $image->media_details->sizes->codilight_lite_block_2_medium->source_url . '"/>';
        echo '<h2><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->title->rendered . '</a></h2>';
        echo '<p>' . $post->excerpt->rendered . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $post->date . '</p>';

        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: tu sabe como usar cURL ao invés de  file_get_contents?
pois por padrão e questão de segurança essa função file_get_contents é desativa nos servidores de hospedagem